# How to modify str_replace_all

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I am trying to standardize species names in a dataframe. I was using `str_replace_all()` to do so. However rather than replacing the old name the function is adding characters onto the new name. The names are mixed, some are already correct and some I need to fix, but I have 30+ species names to adjust. Any tips?

Example code:

```
library(tidyverse)

var1 <- c(1:5)
var2 <- c("Nemophila menziesii", "Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii", "Ceanothus cuneatus", "Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus", "Diplacus auranticus")

df <- as.data.frame(var2, var1)

df %>%
  mutate(var2 = str_replace_all(var2, "Nemophila menziesii", "Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii")) %>%
  mutate(var2 = str_replace_all(var2, "Ceanothus cuneatus", "Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus"))
```

Which outputs:

```
                                             var2
1               Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii
2 Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii var.menziesii
3                 Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus
4    Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus var.cuneatus
5                             Diplacus auranticus
```

Row 2 and 4 is a perfect example of the issue I am having. It should just be "Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus" or "Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work - if you place `$` at the pattern to be replaced it will only replace it when it is the whole string in the variable:

```r
library(tidyverse)

var1 <- c(1:5)
var2 <- c("Nemophila menziesii", "Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii", "Ceanothus cuneatus", "Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus", "Diplacus auranticus")

df <- as.data.frame(var2, var1)

df %>%
  mutate(var2 = str_replace_all(var2, "Nemophila menziesii$", "Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii")) %>%
  mutate(var2 = str_replace_all(var2, "Ceanothus cuneatus$", "Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus"))

#>                                var2
#> 1 Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii
#> 2 Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii
#> 3   Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus
#> 4   Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus
#> 5               Diplacus auranticus
```

In the original examples, `str_replace_all` *is* finding the pattern perfectly in the strings in rows 2 and 4, and replacing them with the replacement string. But that happens *within* the strings and leaves the suffixes in place. The above syntax says "find the pattern only when it doesn't include anything after it".

What you were maybe thinking of is a sort of `if_else` or `case_when` replacement setup? Like the below, which tests for whole string matches and gives same output:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(var2 = case_when(
    var2 == "Nemophila menziesii" ~ "Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii",
    var2 == "Ceanothus cuneatus" ~ "Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus",
    TRUE ~ var2))

#>                                var2
#> 1 Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii
#> 2 Nemophila menziesii var.menziesii
#> 3   Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus
#> 4   Ceanothus cuneatus var.cuneatus
#> 5               Diplacus auranticus
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: No problem! also a brief alternate solution added :)